# Delete a column in a multi-dimensional array if all elements in that column satisfy a condition

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional array such as;

```
a = [[1,1,5,12,0,4,0],
     [0,1,2,11,0,4,2],
     [0,4,3,17,0,4,9],
     [1,3,5,74,0,8,16]]
```

How can I delete the column if all entries within that column are equal to zero? In the array a that would mean deleting the 4th column resulting in:

```
 a = [[1,1,5,12,4,0],
     [0,1,2,11,4,2],
     [0,4,3,17,4,9],
     [1,3,5,74,8,16]]
```

N.b I've written a as a nested list but only to make it clear. I also don't know a priori where the zero column will be in the array.

My attempt so far only finds the index of the column in which all elements are equal to zero:

```
a = np.array([[1,1,5,12,0,4,0],[0,1,2,11,0,4,2],[0,4,3,17,0,4,9],[1,3,5,74,0,8,16]])
b = np.vstack(a)
ind = []
for n,m in zip(b.T,range(len(b.T))):
    if sum(n) == 0:
       ind.append(m)
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

With the code you already have, you can just do:

```
for place in ind:
    for sublist in a:
        del sublist[place]
```

Which gets the job done but is not very satisfactory...

---

Edit: numpy is strong

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(a)
a = a[:, np.sum(a, axis=0)!=0]
```

Comment: I agree, seems abit cumbersome - do you know a more pythonic way?